# How to union two eloquent on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a two eloquent and this is the code on each of them without `union`.
So I want to get all `styles` based on the logged user that is from his `organizations` and `schools`

```
$organization_styles    = Auth::user()->teacher->school->organization->styles;
$school_styles          = Auth::user()->teacher->school->styles;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($organization_styles->toArray());
echo "</pre>";

echo "------------------------";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($school_styles->toArray());
echo "</pre>";
```

and this is the result.

[image]

I want to union it and this is my current test but it gave me error

```
$test = $school_styles->union($organization_styles);
```

Comment: Providing us with the error you're getting would help.

Answer (score 2):

**Collection** class does not have a **union()** method. You're gonna need to use **merge()** method. It should do exactly what you need - it will merge the two collections and make sure styles are not repeated:

```
$styles = $school_styles->merge($organization_styles);
```