# How to add two get() - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two get() :

```
 $nearest_drivers = Driver::where('active', 1)->where('approve', 1)->where('available', 1)->where('vehicle_type', $type_id)->whereIn('id', $nearest_driver_ids)->whereNotIn('id', $meta_drivers2)->limit(10)->get();
 $nearest_drivers2 = Driver::where('active', 1)->where('approve', 1)->where('available', 1)->where('vehicle_type', $type_id)->whereIn('id', $nearest_driver_ids)->whereNotIn('id', $meta_drivers)->limit(10)->get();
```

How do I add `$nearest_drivers2` inside `$nearest_drivers` ?

Like `$nearest_drivers += $nearest_drivers2`

Comment: Welcome to SO ... if you merge them together you lose part of the `whereNotIn` functionality you just called ... what are you actually trying to do with all of this?  do you just want `whereNotIn('id', $meta_drivers2 + $meta_drivers)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to union two eloquent on Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691505/how-to-union-two-eloquent-on-laravel)

Comment: [`Illuminate\Support\Collection::merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-merge)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need union.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions

```php
        $nearest_drivers = Driver::where([
                'active' => 1,
                'approve' => 1,
                'available' => 1,
                'vehicle_type' => $type_id,
            ])
            ->whereIn('id', $nearest_driver_ids)
            ->whereNotIn('id', $meta_drivers2)
            ->limit(10);


        $nearest_drivers2 = Driver::where([
                'active' => 1,
                'approve' => 1,
                'available' => 1,
                'vehicle_type' => $type_id,
            ])
            ->whereIn('id', $nearest_driver_ids)
            ->whereNotIn('id', $meta_drivers)
            ->union($nearest_drivers) // <-- here
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can [merge collections](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-merge) like this:

```php
$nearest_drivers->merge($nearest_drivers2)
```